# How to sort this array this way in python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, row, edit-in-place

You are given an array, for example:

```
arr = [['AB','KR','EH'],['EE','DD','PS'],['GH','LM','XK']]
```

[image: array printed by rows]

Then, through a function, you have to get this:

[image: sorted array printed by rows]

The array must be sorted ascending as a whole and not only by rows. You can not create new arrays for this. You have to do it in place.

I tried to find a way to do this with no new arrays but I could not.
This is my code, it certainly sorts the array but creates a new array.

```
def sortArray(arr): #n : filas,columnas
    sorted_arr = []
    for j in arr:
        sorted_arr.extend(j)

    return sorted(sorted_arr)
```

Comment: In Python these are lists, not arrays. Arrays are in the `numpy` and `array` modules.

Comment: I don't understand the sort order.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see `KR` in the last row. I'm also confused. Shouldn't that be between `GH` and `LM`?

Comment: It is as you said before, Barmar. You have to order it lexicographically.

Comment: Is the array always square or rectangular?

Comment: It is always square.

Comment: Are you ever going to explain the sort order, why KR shall be there?

Comment: @KellyBundy You have to order it lexicographically. KR should be between GH and LM.

Comment: How is KR supposed to be between GH and LM in that image? In what order shall I traverse the grid for that?  And your own code doesn't even produce a 2D list.

Comment: @KellyBundy I know, I think I have to edit that image.

Comment: Still not edited?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a selection sort, using indexes from 0 to `N * N - 1` where `N` is the length of the array (since it's square). The corresponding element in the actual array for each index can be calculated by dividing and taking the remainder.

```py
def sortArray(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n * n):
        m = i
        for j in range(i + 1, n * n):
            if arr[j // n][j % n] < arr[m // n][m % n]:
                m = j
        arr[i // n][i % n], arr[m // n][m % n] = arr[m // n][m % n], arr[i // n][i % n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from itertools import islice

arr = [["AB", "KR", "EH"], ["EE", "DD", "PS"], ["GH", "LM", "XK"]]

i = iter(sorted(v for l in arr for v in l))
for l in arr:
    l[:] = islice(i, 0, len(l))

print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[
  ["AB", "DD", "EE"], 
  ["EH", "GH", "KR"], 
  ["LM", "PS", "XK"]
]
```

Comment: Not the expected result and creates a new list.

Comment: @KellyBundy It doesn't create new list. And the result is correct based of comment *"...You have to order it lexicographically..."*

Comment: `sorted` creates a new list and you know it.

Comment: @KellyBundy It's just temporary variable. The result is stored in existing list `arr`

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: You're interpreting it as "must not return a new list", but I think the whole point is that it's supposed to avoid any list allocation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't create a new list and it has to be done in-place, you could always just do an exchange sort:

```py
arr = [['AB','KR','EH'],['EE','DD','PS'],['GH','LM','XK']]

def sortedArray(arr):
    height = len(arr)
    width = len(arr[0])
    for left in range(height*width):
        for right in range(left+1, height*width):
            li, lj = left//height, left%width
            ri, rj = right//height, right%width
            if arr[li][lj] > arr[ri][rj]:
                arr[li][lj], arr[ri][rj] = arr[ri][rj], arr[li][lj]
    
    return arr

print(sortedArray(arr))
```

Output:

```py
[
 ['AB', 'DD', 'EE'], 
 ['EH', 'GH', 'KR'], 
 ['LM', 'PS', 'XK']
]
```

Looks messy, feels dumb, but at least it does meet the requirements.

Comment: You can make it less messy if you use a translator like I did in my second solution now.

Comment: While I do agree it's more elegant, I feel it's also getting into a grey area concerning the no allocations for new lists, since you are creating a whole class. Wonder if that would be allowed under the rules.

Comment: It's not storing anything, though. And takes O(1) space no matter how large the data is. Not much different than using a few variables and integer objects.

Answer (score 0):

(Result is based on their comments, i.e., not exactly as shown in the incorrect image. And using that they said it's always square.)

#### Solution 1: [Odd insertion sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69437526/12671057) algorithm

```py
a = [['AB','KR','EH'],['EE','DD','PS'],['GH','LM','XK']]

r = range(len(a))
for i in r:
  for j in r:
    for I in r:
      for J in r:
        if a[i][j] < a[I][J]:
          a[i][j], a[I][J] = a[I][J], a[i][j]

print(a)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37yYq2CpER6s7OqnrqHsHAQlXD_VYnWh1V1cg28UFSAQEgwXcPYBsH18gEeGtHhvLxVUE1FmUmJeeqpGTmqeRqKnJlZZfpJCpkJmnUGTFpaAA4mXBeRC-JxIfIuKFIqKgkJmmkBidGRudFatgA2R5xkZ7xSJkFWCSOjA5oCOgLB2YHBdXQVFmXgnQSRBPQv0K8zMA)):

```
[['AB', 'DD', 'EE'], ['EH', 'GH', 'KR'], ['LM', 'PS', 'XK']]
```

#### Solution 2: Ordinary insertion sort

Really ordinary. Just one-dimensional insertion sort. But on an object that translates the indices and gets/sets the values in the two-dimensional original:

```
def insertionSort(A):
  for i, a in enumerate(A):
    while i and a < A[i-1]:
      A[i] = A[i-1]
      i -= 1
    A[i] = a

def sortArray(A):
  class B:
    def __getitem__(_, i):
      return A[i//n][i%n]
    def __setitem__(_, i, value):
      A[i//n][i%n] = value
  n = len(A)
  insertionSort(B())
  return A

arr = [['AB','KR','EH'],['EE','DD','PS'],['GH','LM','XK']]
print(sortArray(arr))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBasMwDL37K3QZjiGllF3GWA8JDSt0g7FeBsYEs6qrIVWC4mz06zOlTbf0Ip7ek96T3Zzioab7h4b7fod7CNQix1DTtuaYZOZRAexrhpCCFxGQuiOyjzhqAD@HUCEE8LSTkSfIbJgt3EWDoXOwHMmRCzBbwkJNZK/UEN5KZsbsT6P5Z@XbFvKL1zBQll8YQ8RjWSZlCsFcYxhjxzTYzefkbLgjN1lqb5ZS@PZVh2Zy4t@S3HIWRSLBFZKcIs3tt@SJGchrqFKeWaat1VmuU715l1KstUutLgrBq5WUt@2ZeF4LfnmV8rHRzqmGA8Xk/@ViZUzf/wI)